# jQuery custom events not working

Tags: jquery

I wanted to have to JS files communicate to each other via jQuery events and thought it would be pretty straight forward but have run into a problem that I think I need help with.

Basically I'm using a DOM element with an ID of '#nav-controller' to act as the messenger between the two JS files. The first file -- and I have checked that it *is* the first one to execute -- listens for two custom events:

```
function external_command_listener () {
    // Click Handling
    $( '#nav-controller' ).on( 'clickhandler' , function ( e , param ) {
        alert ("registering clicks to: " + param );
        register_qs_click_handler ( param );
    });
    // Menu Control handling
    $( '#nav-controller' ).on( 'controlframework' , function ( e , param ) {
        alert ('registering menu handling to: ' + param );
        register_qs_control_framework ( param );
    });
}
```

Now that that's setup. The second file uses trigger() to effectively call the function in first file. Here's the code:

```
function Initialise_Navigation () {
    navTemplate = Template_File_Name ( 'navigation' );
    $.get( navTemplate , function (data) {
        $( '#page-nav-system' ).html(data);
        $( '#nav-controller' ).trigger( 'clickhandler' , ['#application li'] ); // register a click handler
        $( '#nav-controller' ).trigger( 'controlframework' , ['.quicksand-cntrl'] ); // register a control framework
```

I have tested using Chrome's debugger that it does execute the Initialise_Navigation() function and in turn apparently runs both trigger statements but the listeners setup in the first file never activate. I tried it also with just a generic 'click' event but that too failed.

Any ideas? I'm at the end of my rope.

Answer (score 0):

I might be over simplifying this - but, why exactly do you need to implement "communication" between two JS *files*?  Are they in some sort of OO pattern?  Do they run in different scopes?

In any case, you could simply bind the event handler to the `document` object (or any other encompassing *parental* object you have in your DOM tree.

```
// Even binding
$('#parentalElement').bind('customEventString', function(event, params... ) {
  // Handle the event
});

// Trigger 
$('#foo').trigger('custom', params );
```

Comment: the rationale for the communication is that there are two components that have a responsibility and I want to keep dependencies to a minimum (aka, can communicate with the appropriate JS events). This also can help to ensure that synchronisation between these objects is achieved.

Comment: I think the code you're showing is effectively the same as mine, isn't it? Your #parentalElement is my #nav-controller.

Comment: the problem I'm really trying to dig into is, is why doesn't my listener actually pick up events being fired by the "trigger" method.

Comment: You can try using the `.bind()` syntax that I used or alternatively you can try the `.live()` syntax for binding a handler to an event.  If all else fails you can always try binding the handler to the `document` object.  All events should bubble up to the `document` object and you'll be able to catch them there.

Comment: both .bind and .live are old methods and the preferred approach is to use .on instead (live is deprecated, bind is one step removed from formally being deprecated). That's not to say that maybe they'll work where my .on() doesn't. I may give this try later if I can't get it working with .on().

Comment: Yes - `.on()` is the preferred method indeed. Agreed.

Comment: I've tried .bind() no but no love. Still nothing. I'm not even sure how to debug this. I have determined without doubt that (a) listener is in place before trigger, (b) trigger fire, or at least these lines of code execute but nothing happens on the listening side. Arrgh.

Comment: I always find that when I make a stand alone example of the code that is breaking its much easier to debug.  Why don't you try it in http://jsfiddle.net/ then you can post it here and we can tinker with it...

Comment: Thanks Lix. That is a good idea and I appreciate your willingness to help. I am juggling so many balls though and I've decided to solve this problem a different way so while I'm still very intellectually interested in understanding it it is no longer pressing.